# MSBuild Error task show up as a warning in VS

Tags: msbuild

I have an Error task in a C# MSBuild project. The error shows up as a warning in VS2022, below a huge number of other errors that are directly caused by the Error task halting the build. I'd prefer that the other errors don't show up at all, but failing that, the Error task error should at least be on the top of the list and certainly not a mere warning. How can I fix this?

[image]

The Error task looks like this:

```xml
<Target Name="ShowError">
   <Error Text="ToErrIsHuman" Code="CS0518"/>
</Target>
```

The Project has `InitialTargets="ShowError"` to trigger the Error task. The `Code` attribute does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Cannot reproduce; tried both in C++ and C# projects, as a normal target and with InitialTargets, and this alsways turns up as an error in the error list including the code. You'll have to provide additional information (or perhaps try on a clean intall in Sandbox or so).

Comment: It seems to show up in .NET Framework (4.x) projects and only when the .csproj file is modified and the Error added outside VS and reloaded into VS. Restarting VS makes it show up as an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error shows up in 4.x .NET Framework projects. Restart Visual Studio to fix.